# Replace "0" elements in array with values from other array keeping indices and order

Tags: arrays, ruby, replace

I have an array `a` of n numbers and other array `b` with same size filled with "0" and other array `x` with elements of the first array to be replaced. I want to replace the elements of `x` in the array `b` with the order and positions of the array `a`. For example:

```
a = [10, 8, 6, 9, 12, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 7, 9, 6, 10, 4]

b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

x = [5, 3, 8, 4, 10]
```

After replace `b` should be:

```
b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here. What happens if `x` isn't found in `a` or if it's found multiple times?

Comment: Is there any reason b is all zeros?  May an answer hard-code zero and ignore the `b` array?  If not, then the question would be clearer if `b` had distinct values in it (e.g. `b = [0, 1, 2, ...]`)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty straightforward solution:

```
haystack = [10, 8, 6, 9, 12, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 7, 9, 6, 10, 4]
needle = [5, 3, 8, 4, 10]

idx = haystack.each_cons(needle.size).find_index(needle)
raise "needle not found!" unless idx

zeroes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
zeroes[idx, needle.size] = needle
p zeroes
# => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note that this isn't the most efficient solution. It's *O(nm)* (not including initializing `n - x.size` arrays, which isn't free), and a [Boyer-Moore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)–style search would be *O(n)* after pre-processing (*O(m+k)*), but if your data is small the above should be perfectly suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one 5 in the array a. I suggest you iterate through a until you find the position of 5 in a. Then use that index to change the value's in b at the desired index.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_b(a,x)
  mx = a.size - x.size
  return nil if mx < 0
  idx = mx.times.find { |i| a[i,x.size] == x }
  return nil unless idx
  Array.new(a.size,0).tap { |ar| ar[idx, x.size] = x }
end

x = [5, 3, 8, 4, 10]

a = [10, 8, 6, 9, 12, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 7, 11, 6, 10, 4]
make_b(a,x)
  #=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0] 

a = [10, 8, 6, 9, 12, 5, 3, 8, 4, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 4]
make_b(a,x)
  #=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 8, 4, 10, 0]

a = [10, 8, 6, 9, 12, 5, 3, 8, 4, 13, 7, 11, 6, 10, 4]
make_b(a,x).nil?
  #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution only requires using `a` and `x` (`b` is returned), and takes one pass over each of the arrays:

```
 i = 0
 a.map do |e|
   if e == x[i]
     i += 1
     x[i-1]
   else
     0
   end
 end
```